Find value of $a$ in common root of $2$ quadratic equation

If $x^2-ax+4=0$ and $x^2-2x+a=0$ has one common root . Then find $a$ is

What I try : Let $\displaystyle x=\alpha$ be the common root of above equation. Then
$\displaystyle \alpha^2-a\alpha+4=0\cdots (1)$
$\displaystyle \alpha^2-2\alpha+a=0\cdots (2)$
So we have  $\displaystyle \alpha=\frac{a-4}{2-a}$
Put in to $(1),$ We get
$\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{a-4}{2-a}\bigg)^2-a\bigg(\frac{a-4}{2-a}\bigg)+4=0$
$\displaystyle (a-4)^2-a(a-4)(2-a)+4(2-a)^2=0$
$\displaystyle a^3-a^2-16a+32=0$
But answer given is integer.
Plz have a look what,s wrong with above trial solution. Thanks
Now above is cubic equation ,

What is the official solution?

Should say:  I think the downvote here is hard to understand.  The question is clearly stated and the OP has provided a detailed and rational analysis. What more is desired?

Can you link an image of the question? There might be a typo. The question is indeed clearly stated and has a correct solution, but obviously this can't be an integer solution. Correcting the typo would resolve the problem  nicely.

I tried it with sum and product for the three roots: $u+v=a$, $u \cdot v = 4$, $u+w = 2$ and $u \cdot w = a$. I don't get an answer (at least, not an easy one) but there might be an error in the question.

@Dominique If the OP would tell us the official solution ( I suppose that it will say $a=-4$), then we are sure about the typo. So I am waiting...

@Dietruch Burde You are right. There is a typing mistake.

Suppose that the second equation is given by $x^2-2x+\color{#c00}{2}a=0$. In other words, there is a small typo above.
Then we obtain $\alpha=-2$, if not $a=2$. But for $a=2$ we have more than one common root, because both equations are then identical.
So $\alpha=-2$ and the cubic equation reduces to $a=-4$. Indeed, the two equations are then $x^2+4x+4=0$ and $x^2-2x-8=0$. They have exactly one common root, namely $\alpha=-2$.
So the answer then is unique and an integer, namely
$$
a=-4.
$$
